Как выбрать все файлы в папке, включая файлы без расширения, исключив каталоги?
Я использую glob.glob(patch+'*.*'), что позволяет выбрать только файлы с расширением.
Можно ли одним запросом выбрать все файлы, включая те, что без расширения, или нужно использовать цикл для проверки типа каждого объекта (файл или папка)?

придется отсеивать. можно не wиклом, а списковым включением череp атрибут is_file(). и еще, не patch, а path.

Может проще запустить find и взять результат ее работы?


Придётся отсеивать. Можно не циклом, а списковым включением через атрибут is_file() © strawdog

В комментариях @strawdog уже ответил на вопрос, так что продемонстрирую реализацию:
from pathlib import Path
from typing import NamedTuple, List

class DirectoryContents(NamedTuple):
    files: List[Path]
    directories: List[Path]

def get_directory_contents(path: Path) -> DirectoryContents:
    files = [f for f in path.iterdir() if f.is_file()]
    directories = [d for d in path.iterdir() if d.is_dir()]
    return DirectoryContents(files=files, directories=directories)

path = Path(r'C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop')
contents = get_directory_contents(path)

print("Файлы:")
for file in contents.files:
    print(file)

print("\nПапки:")
for directory in contents.directories:
    print(directory)

Вывод:
Файлы:
C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\1.py
C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\13.py
C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\13.spec
C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\13.xlsx
и т.д..

Папки:
C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\Amgarak
C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\build
C:\Users\Amgarak\Desktop\dist
и т.д..


Грамотный ответ на неграмотный вопрос! И как вам удаётся понимать такие поставленные задачи?) В прочем, как и всегда) (автору вопроса не в качестве оскорбления, а в качестве критики)

@Chaos_Sower Да вроде вопрос достаточно понятен, если прочитать его пару раз+)

Слушайте, а может автор вопроса имел в виду другое? С файлами без расширения (допустим, простой test.txt, у которого будет удалён формат расширения [test.txt → test]) ваш код будет работать?

@Chaos_Sower да, метод is_file() вернёт True даже если у файла не будет расширения. Это значит, что в items[0] попадут все файлы с расширением и без него.

Вот вы экономите одну переменную и запутываете этим код. Сделали бы две переменные files и folders, например, в отдельных строках и не путали людей. Сейчас приходится думать, что вы там в items наворотили то ли цикл в цикле, то ли два отдельных цикла - с первого взгляда непонятно )

@CrazyElf да переменных не жалко, но тогда можно и функцию организовать, упаковать всё в именованный кортеж и приправить типизацией в общем, дополнил ответ;)

Готовый консольный скрипт для тестирования:
import os

print("-" * 60 + "\nСписок всех файлов в подкаталогах заданного каталога:\n" + "-" * 60)

directory = r"D:\\DOCUMENTS"
if not os.path.exists(directory): print(f"Каталог {directory} не найден!")
else:
 lst_files = [os.path.join(root, file) for root, _, files in os.walk(directory) for file in files]
 if lst_files:
  for i in lst_files: print(i)
 else: print(f"Каталог {directory} не содержит файлов!")

print("\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul" if os.name == "nt" else "read > /dev/null")


разверните списовое включение - оно не читается... или хотяб скобки поставьте

@FoxFox Код можно вставлять без пробелов, вот так: ~~~python\n ваш код \n~~~ и тогда отступы не будут съезжать.

@Amgarak они не съезжают, это авторский стиль "отступ = один пробел"

Код работает? Какие проблемы? Нечем заняться? Мне - есть, кроме бесполезной писанины, то есть флуда.

Он написан плохо, некачественно. Пепа не соблюдена. Он непонятен, аудитория будет мучиться, читая ответ. Он не рассчитан на массы. Вот будете писать ответы как следует, так чтоб мне понравилось, тогда и буду плюсовать.

Вот взять хотя бы это: "Исправить можно заменой попытки вызова queue_silver.checking через threading на запуск фонового асинхронного таска c помощью asyncio.create_task". Это о чём. Что за птичий язык? Что за РУССКИЙ язык? Кому это написано? Мне не разъяснено! Я не понимаю! Взялись писать советы  и ответы, делать это надо так, чтоб я и все другие понимали. Иначе это замусоривание сайта бесполезной инфоримацией.

@FoxFox ссылаетесь не "пепа", а сами его в своих ответах нарушаете. А так хоть всех тут заминусуйте, больше походит на реакцию обиженного ребёнка ‍♀️

"пепа". Слова не мужа, но мальчика. Ладно, с вами связываться - только нервы тратить.

Вот именно, давно уже пора понять, что если нечего сказать ПО СУТИ, то молчание - золото. Когда будет что сказать, милости просим.
